# How can I make this scalebar more visible?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have this simple spatial scalebar, made using only matplotlib's [arrow](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html) and [text](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html), displayed over a grainy image.
I'm looking for ideas to improve its visualization.

[This is the plot, it shows a top subfigure with a noisy 2D data plot in blues palette, with a colorbar on the bottom. Overlaid is a grey scale bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2ywK.jpg)

Changing the color to black didn't improve the visualization. Moving its position to the bottom left and bottom right didn't help either.

Edit: while I can't provide the same code used for this image, here it's a code that would show a similar situation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n=100
a  = np.random.normal(0,1,size=(n,n))

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
plt.set_cmap('PuBu')
ax.grid(False)
ax.imshow(a,vmin=-1,vmax=2)

ax.arrow(n/3,n/5,n/3,0,color='#555555',lw=2.5, head_width=0, head_length=0)
ax.text(n/2,n/5-n*0.02,'1 unit',ha='center',color='#555555',weight='bold')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Draw the "scalebar" over a semi transparent white box.